# RubyにおいてCPUのメモリ使用量を確認する

Tags: ruby

RubyにおいてCPUのメモリ使用量を確認したいです．
サイト等調べましたが，オブジェクトがなんとか〜で私にとって難しくよく分かりません．

例えば，以下のメソッドを実行したときのメモリ使用量を確認するためにはどうすればよいのでしょうか．
ご教授宜しくお願いします．

```
def hello
  (0 ... 10).each do |i|      
    puts "Hello World: #{i}"
  end
end
```

（追記）
私が使用しているOSはmacOS Sierraです．
メモリ使用量を知りたい理由として，大規模なシミュレーションをスパコンにジョブを投げ，実行する際に，1ノード当たりに使用できるメモリ量が限られているため，現在の私のシミュレーションでどの程度メモリを使用しているかを事前にローカルで確認したいためです．

Comment: 実行しているOSはなんですか？　あと仮想メモリを使うOSにおいて「メモリ使用量」ってのは何種類もあるものです。どれを見たいですか、というか、見て何に使います？　その辺を追記してもらうと回答が付きやすくなるでしょう。

Comment: @774RR 追記しました

Comment: GCがある言語では、「1.動作するのに最低限必要なメモリ量」、「2.最大で使われるかも知れないメモリ量」、「3.そこそこ動作するのに十分なメモリ量」はそれぞれ違います。一体どれを必要としているのですか？ただ、単純に実際に使われたメモリ使用量を調べても、その時の環境やGC実行のタイミングによって変わってくるため、1.2.3.のいずれにもあてははまりません。必要なものに応じて工夫が必要になります。

Comment: @らっしー 1ノード当たりに使用できるメモリ量は制限されているため，「最大で使われるかもしれないメモリ量」を知り，許容メモリ量を超えないように対策をしたいです